# Is it feasible to hitch-hike from Slahpa/Sørfjord to Gåsluokta/Kjøpsvik?

Tags: sea-travel, hitchhiking, norway

The trail [Gränsleden/Rádjebalges](http://www.gellivare.se/sv/Kommun/Kultur/Gransleden/English/) connects Ritsem (Sweden) to Slahpa/Sørfjord in Tysfjord ([Tysfjord kommune page about the trail](https://www.tysfjord.kommune.no/grenseleden.96273.no.html)).  Unfortunately, there is no public transportation (and no road) from Sørfjord to the nearest road at Gåsluokta/Kjøpsvik, chartering a boat will cost thousands of Norwegian crowns, and the landscape does not permit hiking; indeed, usually people walk Gränsleden in large groups of at least 10–15 people (to share the costs for pre-booked boat transport).  In Slahpa/Sørfjord are a wind power plant and two water power plants.  Do people from Gåsluokta/Kjøpsvik work there on a daily basis, and is it feasible to hitch-hike over the fjord?  Or is the power plant mostly unmanned?  I'm quite sure they would take a lone hiker, but it only works if they are there in the first place.

**Update:** [Statens Kartverk topographical map for the area](http://kart.statkart.no/adaptive2/default.aspx?gui=1&lang=2&minX=547789.28125&minY=7546662.53125&maxX=577154.15625&maxY=7562466.25&layers=&baselayer=100&visibleOLOverlays=avinetBasemap100002,avinetBasemap2).

Comment: I have asked the same question [in Scandinavian on the Norwegian fjellforum](http://www.fjellforum.no/topic/28516-transport-slahpas%C3%B8rfjord-till-g%C3%A1sluoktakj%C3%B8psvik/), to increasee exposure and the probability I will get a useful reply.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is the reason a group of 15 can walk the trail and one person can't?

Comment: @BartArondson Because they can share the ca 3000 NOK (400 EUR, 500 USD) boat taxi with 15 people

Comment: So your question is if the employees of the power plants live in Gåsluokta/Kjøpsvik?

Comment: @uncovery Well, perhaps the entire power-plant is remotely controlled.

Comment: @gerrit can you add google locations to the map? this is really hard to pinpoint. I cannot find Slahpa for example.

Comment: @uncovery I've added a link to a Norwegian topographic map (I don't think Google Maps has the placenames).

Comment: @gerrit I do not even see a road from Slahpa to Gåsluokta/Kjøpsvik. so you want to hitchhike on a boat I assume?

Comment: @uncovery Yes.  I thought that was clear from the question, but I will update accordingly.  If there was a road, I would just walk and try, but walking isn't possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12029/discussion-between-uncovery-and-gerrit)

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a [small village in Slahpa](http://www.visitnorway.com/us/VN/Map/?c=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&e=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&p=EFBtJicOO&t=1), I would assume that anybody who has to commute daily to the [power plants at lake Bryn](http://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rfjord_I_kraftverk) south-east from there would live in Slahpa since they cantake a road instead of commuting daily with a boat from Kjøpsvik, after which the person would still need a car to drive up to the plant.

Maybe there is a higher chance of a group hiring a boat that you can go along with than someone going there daily for work on his own boat.

There might be a chance however that there are daily boats with supplies going to Slahpa lodges and residents that you can tag along on.

Comment: Well, I can make the same assumptions.  *Is there anybody who has to commute daily to the power plants at lake Bryn*?  And *does anybody actually live in Slahpa/Sørfjord*?